# Ionic2 - can't open a page in the side menu, after dismissing the modal

Tags: ionic2

**The problem:**

I have to close a Modal and that by returning back to the root view, for that I do the below piece of code:

> this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);

It works fine and goes back to the root view, the only problem is that I have a side menu on that root page (HomePage), I can open it fine, but when I click to open any page existing on that menu, it does not show up and it goes back to the root page again (it dismisses the menu) and does not open the pages knowing the it runs the content of the page I clicked on *I knew it doing a console.log*

Hierarchy of what happens (Step By Step)

(Dismiss) Second page

```
  |____ (Show) Root Page

      |____ (Open) SideMenu
           |___ (click to open a page that exists on SideMenu)
                |___ BOOM (it does not open the page I clicked, dismissed the sideMenu)
```

**Expected behavior**

When closing the modal and back the root page, then going to the side menu, it should open the page I clicked on.

Hierarchy of what should happen

```
(Dismiss) Second page
        |____ (Show) Root Page
               |____ (Open) SideMenu
                           |___ (click to open a page that exists on SideMenu)
                                        |___ Opens Page 3
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Setup a modal that opens from the root, with a side menu too.
2. Close the modal you opened using `this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);`
3. Click on a page that exists on that side menu.

My Ionic info:

```
 Cordova CLI: Not installed
 Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
 Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
 ios-deploy version: Not installed
 ios-sim version: Not installed
 OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
 Node Version: v4.4.7
 Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

Is there anyone know how can I solve that?

Comment: Could you please add your code in a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gC6svdESXYCpyLCp4Ait?p=preview)?

Comment: I have this same issue--did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Have u try setting the rootpage on modal handle? see code below.

```
let modal = this.modal.create("ReviewridePage");
modal.present();

//setroot onmodaldiddismiss
modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot("HomePage");
});
```